# Natbib Error \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Tags: bibtex, natbib, auxiliary-files

I have a problem with `natbib` and `unsrtnat` in compilation.

The error is : `Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

The error is raised by this line of the `aux` file :

`\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

This is the `aux` file :

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\catcode `:\active 
\catcode `;\active 
\catcode `!\active 
\catcode `?\active 
\@input{Pagedegarde/pagedegarde.aux}
\providecommand \oddpage@label [2]{}
\select@language{french}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{french}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{french}}
\@input{Dedicace/dedicace.aux}
\@input{Remerciements/remerciements.aux}
\@input{Resume/resume.aux}
\@input{Abstract/abstract.aux}
\@writefile{@@@}{\chapterbegin }
\@input{Abbreviation/abbreviation.aux}
\@input{Notations/notations.aux}
\citation{McCandless2016}
\@writefile{@@@}{\chapterbegin }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{Table des figures}{19}{table.0.4}}
\@writefile{@@@}{\chapterbegin }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{Liste des tableaux}{21}{table.0.4}}
\@input{Chapitre1/chapitre1.aux}
\@input{Chapitre2/chapitre2.aux}
\@input{Chapitre3/chapitre3.aux}
\@input{Chapitre4/chapitre4.aux}
\@input{Chapitre5/chapitre5.aux}
\@input{Chapitre6/chapitre6.aux}
\bibdata{Biblio/Bibich}
\bibstyle{unsrtnat}
\@input{Publications/Publications.aux}
\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
\global\mtcsecondpartfalse
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: I get no error. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this minimum example provides no error. I get the error when I run my thesis document which has several files in it. Basically the code should be similar, the only difference I see is the several files thing.

Comment: Sorry but why do think it useful to show code that doesn't give an error? And obviously the code is not similar if you get once an error and once not. Come back when you have failing example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer fair enough. I updated the question and presented the `aux` file. Will this help ?